# Pycharm won't run program

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm learning Python through a youtube tutorial and took a break of over a month to deal with life. When I returned and tried to run a program I created along with the instructor in Pycharm (Community 2020.2.1) it gives me this error in the console:

> Error:Cannot run program
> "/home/user/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/bin/python" (in directory
> "/home/user/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld"): error=2, No such file or
> directory

Except I can browse to /home/user/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/bin/, and see the "python" file. Running the file by double-clicking on it returns the following error in Pycharm:

> Cannot find file
> '/home/user/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/bin/python'

When I go to create a new project, the New Project window does not list any interpreter. Is that my issue?

I've tried reinstalling Pycharm and multiple solutions from Stack and other resources without success. I had no issues with Pycharm at all in July. If it matters; this is the Pycharm that's available in the Linux Mint 19.3 Software Manager.

How can I fix this? Why would taking a break cause this issue?

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? Do you get the same error if you start Pycharm as root?

Comment: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/open-programs-with-root-access-linux/ I get an "pycharm: command not found" error when I enter "sudo -s", then "pycharm" in the terminal.

Comment: It depends on which version you installed. Try `sudo pycharm-community`. If that doesn't work, find the install directory and open a terminal there and/or add that directory to the PATH.

Comment: Finally found it (https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community). Apparently Mint installs Pycharm as a Flatpak (whatever that means). Opened program as root and error still occurs.

Comment: Please check `File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter` and `Run - Edit Configurations - <corresponding configuration>` settings. There should be no warnings.

Comment: I see an error in File-Settings, but it wasn't there when I first opened that window; I changed the interpreter from *Python 3.7 (HelloWorld)* to *Project Default (Python 3.7 (HelloWorld))* in Run-Edit Configuration window (which didn't help my original problem). Only after I did that did the error seen in File-Settings appear. 
https://i.imgur.com/FnT9d4C.png
https://i.imgur.com/h3YHGRW.png

Comment: For clarity of the above post: the *Invalid Python SDK* window seen in the first pic appears after I click "Install packaging tools"

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same issue after I upgraded my macOS to Catalina. In a nutshell, you need to restore broken links in `venv` and the simplest way to do this is to recreate the Python virtual environment for your project.

Here's my step-by-step solution:

1. In PyCharm go to PyCharm > Preferences... > Project  > Python Interpreter
2. Click on the settings icon on the right upper corner then select "Show All..." in the dropdown menu. "Python Interpreters" window should appear.
3. Click on the "-" button on the bottom (it shows "Remove" as a hint). Click OK.
4. Now you should see <No interpreter> on the right side of "Python Interpreter".
5. Open a terminal. Go to your project folder, find and remove `venv` subfolder.
6. Return to PyCharm. Open the same window (PyCharm > Preferences... > Project  > Python Interpreter).
7. Click on the settings icon on the right upper corner then select **"Add.."** in the dropdown menu. "Add Python Interpreter" window should appear.
8. Select "New environment", select the correct location (where the removed `venv` folder was located), select the correct Base interpreter and check "Inherit global site-packages" if your project requires it.
9. Profit!

Worked for me with PyCharm 2020.2.2 Community Edition.